# Javascript nested array keep only specific keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript Array like this and would like to keep only white-listed keys:

```
function cleanArray(arr, whitelist) {
  // remove all non-whitelisted keys from the array
}

let origArr = [
  { keep1: 'abc', keep2: 'def', buh1: false, buh2: false },
  { keep3: 'abc', keep4: 'def', buh3: false, buh4: true },
  { keep5: 'abc', keep6: 'def', buh5: false, buh5: false }
];

let whiteList = ['keep1', 'keep2', 'keep3', 'keep4', 'keep5'];
let resultArr = cleanArray(origArr, whiteList);

// result should look like this
resultArr = [
  { keep1: 'abc', keep2: 'def' },
  { keep3: 'abc', keep4: 'def' },
  { keep5: 'abc', keep6: 'def' } 
];
```

How can I remove all non Whitelisted keys from this Array, without naive parsing the array and constructing a new result array? It does not need to be an immutable operation, I would prefer code readability over that.

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Welcome! Please see the [tour], [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. People will be more apt to help if you show what you've tried.

Comment: OK I edited the question with some better code example - let me know if thus suffices. If not please let me know the concrete point of concern if possible.

Comment: Show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is to help you fix your code when it doesn't work as expected. Not showing any attempts works against you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a *worked* solution:

```js
let arr = [
  { keep1: 'abc', keep2: 'def', buh1: false, buh2: false },
  { keep3: 'abc', keep4: 'def', buh3: false, buh4: true },
  { keep5: 'abc', keep6: 'def', buh5: false, buh5: false }
]

let whiteList = ['keep1', 'keep2', 'keep3', 'keep4', 'keep5'];

arr.forEach(function (obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (whiteList.indexOf(key) == -1) 
      delete obj[key]
  })
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I personally prefer this answer over georgs because it appears better readable for my taste.Thank you both!